# Books to develop a deep understanding of Algorithmic Information Theory?

Tags: big-list, it.information-theory, textbook-recommendation, kolmogorov-complexity

I'm mathematical physicist working with hydrodynamics modelling. Recently, I had to turn to modelling of flows with particles and some questions I have I think are related to Algorithmic Information Theory. I have the general idea (like expected Kolmogorov complexity equals entropy, but this is more general physical intuition and I need more rigour), but I've never worked on AIT neither my colleagues, hence I'm here, asking for textbooks and advanced courses.

Comment: I think it is usual to start with Li and Vitanyi's textbook.

Answer (score 4):

A comprehensive collection of resources is maintained by [Marcus Hutter:](http://www.hutter1.net/ait.htm) Tutorials, Courses, Text Books, and more.